# MongoDB Group By '$group' issue getting records in aggregate function on date we have datetime format in tabel DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, codeigniter-3

I having issue on mongo db with codeignitor3 to getting records using group by '$group' in aggregate function on date as 'created' but we have datetime format in table USER_DATA mongoDb database.
when I run the mongo query I am getting error "can't convert from BSON type string to Date"

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(-1 month));
$users = $this->common_model->aggregate($this->database['USER_DATA'], array(array('$match' => array('created' => array('$gte' => $date))),
        array('$sort' => array('_id.created' => -1)),
        array('$group' => array('_id' => array('year' => array('$year' => '$created'), 'month' => array('$month' => '$created'), 'day' => array('$dayOfMonth' => '$created')), 'count' => array('$sum' => 1))),
        ));
```

before we are using

```
array('$group' => array('_id' => array('created' => '$created')), 'count' => array('$sum' => 1)),
```

Its was working fine but records not as required per group by date, because in DB table we have datetime format.
Is their any way on mongo query with codeignitor library function aggrigation?

Comment: Nobody can help me for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I did alternate option, that is I created another field in table name `"created_date": "2019-01-10"` and I did the group by with "created_date" and its working fine.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(-1 month));
$users = $this->common_model->aggregate($this->database['USER_DATA'], array(array('$match' => array('created' => array('$gte' => $date))),
        array('$sort' => array('_id.created' => -1)),
        array('$group' => array('_id' => array('created_date' => '$created_date')), 'count' => array('$sum' => 1)),
        ));
```

But I want to the way I was asking in question, because sometimes we can't create new extra field just for do it, that's why I try the option I asked in question, I hope in future I will get that solution too. Thank you guys:)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go through Mongodb documentation for [Date conversions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/).

```
var project = {
            "$project":{ 
                "_id": 0,
                "y": {
                    "$year": ISODate("$created").getFullYear() 
                    },
                "m": {
                    "$month": ISODate("$created").getMonth()+1 // months start from 0
                }, 
                "d": {
                    "$dayOfMonth":  ISODate("$created").getDate()
                }
            } 
        },
        group = {   
            "$group": { 
                "_id": { 
                    "year": "$y", 
                    "month": "$m", 
                    "day": "$d"
                },  
                "count" : { "$sum" : "$users" } //Users count
            }
        };
```

Comment: we have datetime format like this "created": "2019-01-02 08:45:57",
thanks for answer, I will check as the way you suggest and let you know the answer.

Comment: @kRitZ, firstly thanks for your help.
I have checked your solution by applying the way you told. But it seem not working. Actually its not the thing that I want. As I told earlier I need data result in group by date and sum of count total no of records creation per date. Your solution is for get result in the date format, as you can see its used in $project array. 
{ $dateFromString: {
     dateString: "06-15-2018",
     format: "%m-%d-%Y"
} }
I tried like the way but its was for the format we are passing. I think your solution is for get date in other format. but I need groupby date.

Comment: I tried like this but not working at all

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-1 MONTH")); //MONTH
  $users = $this->common_model->aggregate($this->database['USER_DATA'], array(
            array('$match' => array('created' => array('$gte' => $date))),
            array('$sort' => array('_id.created' => -1)),
            array('$group' => array('_id' => array('created' => array('$dateFromString' => array('dateString' => '$created', 'format' => '"%Y-%m-%d'))), 'count' => array('$sum' => 1))),
        ));

Comment: and
 
    $users = $this->common_model->aggregate($this->database['USER_DATA'], array(
            array('$match' => array('created' => array('$gte' => $date))),
            array('$sort' => array('_id.created' => -1)),
            array('$group' => array('_id' => array('created' => '$created'), 'count' => array('$sum' => 1))),
array('$project' => array('date' => array('$dateFromString' => array('dateString' => '$created', 'format' => '"%Y-%m-%d')))),
        ));

Comment: Also I am not sure that, it will work, because the $project is for get the result like select id etc, and group by should be just above the $project, but in our case the $project is above and $group in last. So are you sure it will work?

Comment: i believe we can use multiple projections within a single aggregation call.

Comment: $this->common_model->aggregate($this->database['USER'], array(array('$match' => array('created' => array('$gte' => $date))),array('$sort' => array('_id.created' => -1)), array('$project' => array('_id' => 0, 'y' => array('$year' => ISODate('$created').getFullYear()), 'm' => array('$month' => ISODate('$created').getMonth() + 1), 'd' => array('$dayOfMonth'=>ISODate('$created').getDate()))), array('$group' => array('_id' => array("year" => '$y', "month" => '$m', "day" => '$d'), 'count' => array('$sum' => 1))) ));
Error: Call to undefined function ISODate() and getFullYear(), MongoVer:4.0.4

Comment: please see my above last comment, I tried but error,
Error: Call to undefined function ISODate() and getFullYear(), My mongo Db Version :4.0.4

Comment: can you console.log the date from created. It might give better understanding of the issue.

Comment: for console.log i don't know how to do with query generated "$created".  its not the $date we have match condition. if you have some example like this you can share with me.

Comment: For now I did alternative